# Local MySQL server for multiple computers

Tags: mysql, database

I have somewhat of a problem with MySQL databases. I need to host ~10 databases for local development and so far I've done so using WAMP. I do work on my desktop and laptop from time to time and I have trouble syncing the databases without breaking the data.

I've had small success using Dropbox to host the MySQL data and the two computers sync these files from the cloud, but InnoDB is very fragile and breaks the data files too often. I am now looking for solutions as to how I can host these databases for local development and access the database from both computers?

Some solutions I've considered:

- Using my laptop as a server to run WAMP. Originally this was how I did it but it consumes power, requires me to keep my laptop where I can reach it and I have to modify it too often.
- Setting up an online database to be remotely connected to. I can also limit remote connections to my ip address, but data retrieval is obviously slower.
- Hosting a virtual Linux server and maintaining the virtual OS files on Dropbox where I can launch the server from either computer and this server would run Apache\Nginx + MySQL on localhost.

What other solutions are there? What is considered the fastest, most reliable and least troubling?

Comment: a free amazon RDS? https://aws.amazon.com/rds/

Comment: A remote, persistent instance is the most reliable solution here. MySQL replication via something like [DRBD](http://www.drbd.org) is not trivial to set-up and has significant OS dependencies. Using Dropbox *will* be trouble as InnoDB is under no obligations to maintain a consistent dump state. To get consistent data out of it either use `mysqldump` or [`innobackupex`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/innobackupex_script.html).